# using phpBB3 variables in custom php

Tags: php, phpbb3

I'm implementing a custom php script within the viewforum loop to add voting. I need to pass `{topicrow.TOPIC_ID}` to the `voteHTML()`, where `$itembid` currently is. It renders the `data-did` perfectly through the loop. How do I get the variable value through to the `php` block?

```
<span class="topid" data-did="{topicrow.TOPIC_ID}" ></span>
<!-- PHP -->
    echo $pulse->voteHTML($itembid);
<!-- ENDPHP -->
```

Comment: What's the phpBB version?

Comment: phpBB version 3.1

Comment: You're using function in your template. It is a bad way. Avoid logical treatment in your template. You're using 3.1, you should use extensions. Implement logical strategy in your extension file. So you could provide all needed variable in your extension template.

Comment: You're using function in your template. It is a bad way. Avoid logical treatment in your template. You're using 3.1, you should use extensions. Implement logical strategy in your extension file. So you could provide all needed variable in your extension template.